# Custom date time is same but not matching in grok date filter logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

The input is comma separated values:
"2010-08-19","09:12:55","56095675"

I created the custom `date_time` field which appears to right format `2010-08-19;09:12:55` **but not matching**.

```
filter {
 grok {
    match => { "message" => '"(%{GREEDYDATA:cust_date})","(%{TIME:cust_time})","(%{NUMBER:author})"'}
    add_field => {
            "date_time" => "%{cust_date};%{cust_time}"
    }
}

date {
  match => ["date_time", "yyyy-MM-dd;hh:mm:ss"]
  target => "@timestamp"
  add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
}
```

Output on Kibana:

```
cust_date       August 18th 2010, 20:00:00.000
cust_time       09:12:55
date_time       2010-08-19;09:12:55
message         "2010-08-19","09:12:55","56095675"
tags        beats_input_codec_plain_applied, _dateparsefailure
```

It gives `_dateparsefailure`. The fields appear to be same as match pattern.
I tried different time format like `YYYY-MM-dd;hh:mm:ss` and `YYYY-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss`
 What am I doing wrong?
Help!

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `date` plugin inside the `filter` section, right under `grok`.

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => '"(%{GREEDYDATA:cust_date})","(%{TIME:cust_time})","(%{NUMBER:author})"'}
    add_field => {
        "date_time" => "%{cust_date};%{cust_time}"
    }

    date {
        match => ["date_time", "yyyy-MM-dd;hh:mm:ss"]
        target => "@timestamp"
       add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
    }
}
```